# I have two Partial view and I want to hide them depending on dropdownList value change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Two Customer Type And I use Service Known Type in WCF the Customer Type is Main Customer And Sub Customer. I have Dropdown List to select Customer Type When I select The Main Customer I need The Sub Customer Partial View to be hidden And vice versa

```
    @model SoqiaRazorProject.CustomerService.CustomerData

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customer Data";
}

<h2>CustomerData</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer Data</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CardID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CardID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CardID)
        </div>

           <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            @Html.DropDownList("ddlCustomerType",(SelectList)ViewBag.ddlCustomerType,new{@id="ddlCustomerType"})

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NationalityID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ddlNationality")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NationalityID)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FamilyName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FamilyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FamilyName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FatherName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FatherName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FatherName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GrandFatherName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.GrandFatherName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GrandFatherName)
        </div>
```

and I write this J-Query Code to Hide/Show The Partial view

```
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
         <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
                 $("ddlCustomerType").change(function HideControls() {
                     var val = $("ddlCustomerType").val();
                     if (val == 2) {
                         $("MainCustomerDiv").hide();
                         $("SubCustomerDiv").show();
                     }
                     else if (val == 3) {
                         $("SubCustomerDiv").hide();
                         $("MainCustomerDiv").show();
                     }

                 })
             });
             </script>

        <div id="MainCustomerDiv">
            @Html.Partial("MainCustomerData")
        </div>
         <div id="SubCustomerDiv">
            @Html.Partial("SubCustomerData")
        </div>

          <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

When I Run the application "I try to change the dropdown list values But The Partial View Not Hidden"

Comment: I wirte full view code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add # char to your element selectors :)

```
$("#ddlCustomerType").change(function HideControls() {
var val = $("#ddlCustomerType").val();
if (val == 2) {
    $("#MainCustomerDiv").hide();
    $("#SubCustomerDiv").show();
}
else if (val == 3) {
    $("#SubCustomerDiv").hide();
    $("#MainCustomerDiv").show();
}
});
```